# Why secret code is need and why not in OAuth2.0

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, twitter-oauth

Why OAuth2.0 **client secret** is need and why not? Please explain with simple example. I am really confused after RnD.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: last i checked twitter auth was oauth1 not oauth2.

Comment: I just want to know about OAuth2.0 protocol client secret during authorization process.

Answer (score 0):

**Authorization Code Flow**

The client secret is needed during the exchange step (exchange authorization code for access token). The client sends the authorization server its client_id and client_secret so that the authorization server can verify that it really is the client.

I took this picture from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=996OiexHze0 (22:00)

The client_secret is needed in step 3

[Authorization Code Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vktsi.png)

**Implicit Flow**

During implicit flow a client secret is not used as the client does not call the authorization server a 2nd time.

This picture is also from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=996OiexHze0 (44:37)

It shows the implicit flow

[implicit flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzhPb.png)